# When we go to Jannah, can we have children?

Tags: jannah, children

When we go to Jannah, can we have children?  I.e., have a family, not just be with your family. If not then why?

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference of opinions on the interpretation of the hadiths on this topic. The strongest opinion is that one may have one's children in *Jannah* that one had during one's life on Earth, but not give birth to a new offspring therein, and no reason was given in any hadith as to why.

In one hadith, the Prophet ﷺ said that if a believer desires a child in *Jannah*, one's wish would be granted:

> عن أبي سعيد الخدري، قال قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم: الْمُؤْمِنُ إِذَا اشْتَهَى الْوَلَدَ فِي الْجَنَّةِ كَانَ حَمْلُهُ وَوَضْعُهُ وَسِنُّهُ فِي سَاعَةٍ كَمَا يَشْتَهِي
>
> Abu Sa'eed Al-Khudri narrated that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "The believer, when he desires a child in Paradise, he [the baby] shall be carried [in pregnancy], born, and complete his aging in an hour as he desires."
>
> <sub>— [Jami' at-Tirmidhi, Vol. 4, Book 12, Hadith 2563](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/727570)</sub>

In a continuation on the same link above (in the Arabic text only, not translated on Sunnah.com) Is'hāq ibn Ibrāhīm said the believer would give borth if he desires so but he would not desire so. Note that the word "*itha*" (Arabic: إذا) in the hadith was translated in the link above as "when" rather than "if". "*Itha* may be used to mean "when" but the typical use is that it means "if".

In the same link, there is a reference to another hadith:

> وقد روي عن أبي رزين العقيلي، عن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم قال: إِنَّ أَهْلَ الجَنَّةِ لاَ يَكُونُ لَهُمْ فِيهَا وَلَدٌ
>
> <sub>**NOTE.** My own translation, so treat with care.</sub>
>
> It was narrated through Abu Razīn al-'Uqaily that the Prophet ﷺ said: "The dwellers of Jannah will not have children therein."
>
> <sub>— [Jami' at-Tirmidhi, Vol. 4, Book 12, Hadith 2563](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/727570)</sub>

This other hadith and the concept that there will be no giving birth in *Jannah* are further strengthened through another long hadith in *Musnad Ahmad* (partially quoted):

> قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم: َالصَّالِحَاتُ لِلصَّالِحِينَ، تَلَذُّونَهُنَّ مِثْلَ لَذَّاتِكُمْ فِي الدُّنْيَا، وَيَلْذَذْنَ بِكُمْ غَيْرَ أَنْ لَا تَوَالُدَ
>
> <sub>**NOTE.** My own translation, so treat with care.</sub>
>
> The Messenger of Allah ﷺ said: " The righteous women will be there for the righteous men to enjoy as you enjoyed in this world, and they will enjoy you, but there will be no giving birth.
>
> <sub>— [Musnad Ahmad, Vol. 27, pp. 126](https://al-maktaba.org/book/25794/12674#p1) (Arabic only)</sub>

[Ibn Qayyim al-Jawziyya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Qayyim_al-Jawziyya) in *Hādi al-Arwāh Ila Bilād al-Afrāh* [249](https://al-maktaba.org/book/11147/247#p2) (Arabic only) said that what goes on in *Jannah* is a matter of the unseen, so we do not know for sure what will happen there. However, he added that it was his opinion that there will be no giving birth in *Jannah* because:

- The hadith of Abu Sa'īd al-Khudri is conditional as it said that "if a believer desires a child", and it may be the case that no believer would desire so in *Jannah*.
- The hadith of Abu Sa'īd al-Khudri was narrated through Abu as-Siddīq an-Nāji, who had poor command of words that he memorized (hence, the *hassan* or good grade of the hadith). He narrated the same hadith in three different forms that the believer will have children in *Jannah* (a) and he will desire so, (b) when he desires so, or (c) if he desires so.
- There is more than one hadith, although they have their own issues in their chain of narration, that point to the option of no giving birth in *Jannah*.

You may refer to Islam Q&A's article ["Will there be pregnancy and childbirth in Paradise?"](https://islamqa.info/en/111777) for more information.